# Как правильно отделить PHP код от HTML?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, webview, проектирование

С вебом начал знакомится только недавно, и сразу же возник вопрос как правильно отделить шаблон HTML от кода PHP, так что бы верстальщику не пришлось ковыряться в PHP-скриптах.

Ну, например, сделаю я сайт в скриптах которого весь HTML будет выводится через `echo()` и через некоторое время верстальщик решит что-то поменять тогда же ему придется ковыряться во всей этой помойке что не есть тру.

Кто что может подсказать по этой теме, а лучше порекомендуйте что нибудь почитать

Comment: покажите пример где весь HTML выводится через echo()
от такого кода избавляться надо

Comment: Ниже на ответ Андрея посмотрите

Comment: @ConstantineVolochshuk, тогда вы меня не совсем поняли. Там не html-код выводится через `echo`, а в html-коде есть вставки `echo`, которые выводят значения из переменных, которые в свою очередь уже не верстальщиком, а программистом где-то в отдельном файле считаются. И тогда получается, что верстальщик знает верстку и названия переменных, которые нужно вывести, а вот откуда они берутся - дело программиста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сайт в виде сингл пейдж, когда клиентская часть полностью на `HTML` + `CSS` + `JS` + `REST API` на `PHP`. [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) или [Angular](https://angularjs.org) для клиентской части + сервер на чем угодно.
2. PHP фремворк с архитектурой MVC (большинство php фреймворков). Не сложно освоить верстальщику вьюхи. Например [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com).
3. Шаблонизаторы [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) или [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)

Answer (score 0):

Например и вам и верстальщику освоить какой-нибудь шаблонизатор. Smarty, Twig или еще что-то

Comment: Это единственный выход из данной ситуации? Как вообще поступают профессиональные разработчики?

Comment: А чем это не выход? Еще, как вариант XSLT преобразование. Верстальщик делает страницу, а вы из нее делаете конечный результат. Сам не делал и мне кажется, что HTML на входе должен быть валидным XML. Это будет доп. требованием к верстальщику

Comment: Просто мне показалось что многие не любят работать с  шаблонизаторами. XSLT - заинтересовал, но опять же его должен знать верстальщик. А вообще это нормально пихать HTML в echo()?

Comment: @ConstantineVolochshuk XSLT должен знать только программер. По сути от верстальщика получите просто страницу (может даже с примерами контента). Программист при помощи XSLT вставляет на указанные им места контент, например из базы.

Comment: @ConstantineVolochshuk "...показалось что многие не любят работать с шаблонизаторами". Откуда такая информация?

Comment: Ну вот хотя бы статья на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/post/30675/

Comment: @ConstantineVolochshuk Статья очень старенькая и весьма субъективная. Шаблонизаторы с тех пор стали гораздо лучше. Кроме того с ними, как и с другими инструментами, нужно уметь работать. Для этого нужно, как минимум, почитать документацию, а не использовать материалы из статей семилетней давности

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку php сам по себе является некоторым шаблонизатором, можно сделать что-то типа такого:

```
<?php
    //тут что-то считается
    $result['some_element1'] = $some_value1;
    $result['some_element2'] = $some_value2;
    $result['some_element3'] = array();
?>

<!-- А тут собственно сама верстка с вставкой в нужные места результатов -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div> <?php echo $result['some_element1']; ?> </div>
    <p> <?php echo $result['some_element2']; ?> </p>
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach($result['some_element3'] as $row){
                echo "<li>" . $row . "</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: в пхп придумали шотхенд <?=$result['some_element1'];?> вроде.
вот [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) подробно и красиво все расписано.

Comment: @DmitryV., Да, вроде есть и укороченные варианты, с ними еще проще будет. А вот ссылка, которую вы дали говорит про абсолютно другое.

Comment: Вот как раз это мне и не нравится. У вас тег <li>  находится в одной  куче с PHP кодом. Как верстальщик поймет что тут происходит ?

Comment: Ну все (наверное) шаблонизаторы используют какой-то свой язык как минимум для вывода переменных и циклов. Поэтому что верстальщику придется дополнительно разобраться немного в php, что где-то еще - все равно разбираться. В добавок, собственно знать из команд надо только `echo` - вывод, `foreach` - цикл, в котором вывод сделать и `include` - подключить кусок другого шаблона.